# Studying a sequence: $x_{n+1} = x_n + \frac{1}{a}\cdot x_n^{1-a}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Suppose a sequence $(x_n)_{n\ge0}, \:$ as $\: \: x_{n+1} = x_n + \frac{1}{a}\cdot x_n^{1-a}\: \: \: \forall n \ge 0, a\ge 1,  x_0 =1$.

I have found $x_1 = \frac{1}{a} + 1$, deduced all terms are positive and that $(x_n)$ is ascending.

I have to find $$\lim _{n \to \infty} x_n$$
and $$\lim _{n \to \infty} \frac{x_n^a}{n}$$

I tried solving the first limit and I want to know if this way of thinking is correct:

By assuming the limit exists and $\lim _{n \to \infty} x_n = l \Rightarrow l = l + \frac{1}{a}\cdot l^{1-a} \Rightarrow l^{1-a} = 0 $ s0 $l = 0$. That would mean that if the limit existed it would be $0$. That means $(x_n)$ diverges (because we know $x_n > 0 \:\forall n \ge 0$),  and $x_n$ tends to $\infty$ as n goes to $\infty$. If this is correct, would that apply if there was an equality like $2l = 2l $ ? Can also say in this case that the series diverge ?

Comment: Is $0 < a < 1$?

Comment: @DeepSea Edited, $a \ge 1$

Comment: Newton Raphson for $f(x) = e^{-x^a}$. So looks like divergent might be correct. (This is handwaving though)

Comment: @Aryabhata Isn't what I wrote correct ?

Comment: If $a>1$, then $1-a<0$, and therefore you cannot conclude from $l^{1-a}=0$ that $l=0$; rather, the equation $l^{1-a}=0$ has no solution for $l$. Note however that in that case, $\lim_{l\to\infty} l^{1-a}=0$.

Comment: @celtschk So that doesn't mean $(x_n)$ diverges ? I don't really know much about this "method".

Comment: @Liviu: It means that your argument at that point is erroneous. Indeed, the very fact that the equation has no solution already implies that the sequence diverges, as if a limit would exist, it would solve that equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applying Stolz-Cesaro's theorem to the second limit we get

$$\lim _{n \to \infty} \frac{x_n^a}{n} = \lim _{n \to \infty} \frac{x_{n+1}^a - x_n^a}{n+1-n} = \lim _{n \to \infty} (x_n + \frac{1}{a}\cdot x_n^{1-a})^a - x_n^a = \lim _{n \to \infty} x_n^a[(1+\frac{1}{a} \cdot x_n^{-a})^a - 1] = \lim _{n \to \infty} x_n^a \cdot \frac{(1 + \frac{1}{a\cdot x_n^a})^a - 1}{\frac{1}{a\cdot x_n^a}}\cdot \frac{1}{a\cdot x_n^a} = a \cdot \frac{1}{a} = 1$$

I used $$\lim _{n \to \infty} \frac{(1+x_n)^a - 1}{x_n} = a$$
where $$\lim _{n \to \infty} x_n = 0$$